# jQuery Ajax - Refresh data in the DIV with pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need help on refreshing the data inside a DIV. I have DIV which loads the ajax page that populates data in a table format. When user searches for a CompanyName, it triggers and refreshes the data inside the DIV, and it is working fine.  However, the ajax page has pagination (Previous | Next ...).  If user clicks on the Previous|Next link, it will jump to the Ajax page.

Is there any Jquery or Ajax trick that I could perform pagination within the DIV with the result data feedback from the Ajax?  Like user clicks in the the link from the ajax data (in the Div) and it just refresh the ajax data only without jump to the actual Ajax page?

jQuery codes:

```
$('#CompanyName').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        //alert("Found");
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),              
            url: 'ajaxPurchaseRequestList.asp',
            success: function(res) {
                $('#ResultTest').html(res); 
            }

        });
    }
});
```

The ASP codes in my Ajax page. This basically show the Previous|Next links, and when use click the link, it will send the URL with "?pagenum=x".

```
If abspage = 1 Then
  Response.write "<span style=""color:silver;"">Previous Page</span>"
Else
  Response.write "<a href=""" & Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") & "?pagenum=" & abspage - 1 & """>Previous Page</a>"
End if
Response.write "&nbsp;|&nbsp;"

If abspage < pagecnt then
  Response.write "<a href=""" & Request.servervariables("SCRIPT_NAME") & "?pagenum=" & abspage + 1 & """>Next Page</a>"
Else
```

Thank you,

Comment: Try moving the pagination HTML to the UI (i.e. your JavaScript). Then handle the click events with jQuery using [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Each click is a separate Ajax call, which passes in the requested page number. In addition, I recommend for the ajaxPurchaseRequestList.asp script to return JSON instead of HTML. It should, in addition to the company name you're serializing, accept the page number. I hope this helps. But I would evaluate whether you truly need pagination. I'm assuming this is an autocomplete problem?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I do need pagination. Basically, the filter results may have around few thousand records. I am new to jQuery, would you please give me some sample codes of the method you described above?

Comment: I'm afraid that since the answer is too broad, I'm unable to provide an example. I'd also have to google for examples as well. However, have you considered only returning closest matches and up to a given maximum, perhaps top 10 or 50 matches? Perhaps returning thousands of records is too much. I'm trying to help you look at the problem from a different angle. You can look for jQuery autocomplete plugins that can help you simplify the UI.

Comment: Filtering matches around lesser than 100 is not an option for me. For example, I have 30K companies, and user can type "Net" will match more than 1000 records already. I am just looking for the solution of how to refresh the result in the ajax with pagination, but not really familiar with Ajax.  I will do more research.  Thanks anyway.